Deserialize Object in .net standard which was serialized in .NET framework
I have a client-server application which runs on .NET Framework v4.8. Now I've migrated parts of the application to .NET Standard 2.0. The .NET Standard parts are used by the client and the server.
The client (WPF) communicates with the server (ASP.NET) over SOAP. This just worked fine as long as the complete application was in .NET framework.
Now when I make a soap-request from the client (.NET Framework) to the server I get the following exception:

System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (2, 2).
Inner Exception:
FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

The exception is thrown in the XmlSerializer.xml in the following code:
public object Deserialize(TextReader textReader)
{
    XmlTextReader xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(textReader);
    xmlTextReader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.Significant;
    xmlTextReader.Normalization = true;
    xmlTextReader.XmlResolver = null;
    return Deserialize(xmlTextReader, null);
}

Where do I have to add the reference to System.Memory 4.0.1.1 and where do I get exactly this version? I can't find that specific version in nuget.

What is your Deserialize(xmlTextReader, null) second method doing? If this is serializing implementation rather than just data, then ... yeah, that's going to be painful. Exactly how is the SOAP part of this configured? The specific tools involved here will be directly relevant in terms of discovering whether you have any configuration options here to work around this. SoapFormatter has been considered deprecated since .NET Framework 2.0, so: since basically forever.

as a side note: netstandard is basically some subset of overlapping APIs that happen to exist (give of take) - it is essentially the "worst of both"; it is usually preferable to multi-target rather than target netstandard (for example <TargetFrameworks>net48;net8.0</TargetFrameworks>

I'm not sure it is possible.  You are using two different versions of the library.  I would use Net 4.8 to deserialize the data and then serialize the data with Net-Standard 2.0.
